# How to infer the types of columns without hardcoding their names?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

My input is a `csv` file :

```
col1,col2,col3
A,13/01/2023,1
B,14/01/2023,2
C,15/01/2023,3
```

When I import it using Power Query, I get this auto generated code :

```vb
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\VERBOSE\Desktop\file.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"En-têtes promus" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"En-têtes promus",{{"col1", type text}, {"col2", type date}, {"col3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Type modifié"
```

The problem is that the file I receive may sometimes have missing columns or new ones. And even worse, sometimes the same column name may have different types accross two consecutives files.

And that throws some annoying errors :

> `Expression.Error` : Désolé... Nous n'avons pas trouvé la colonne « col4
> » de la table. Détails :
> col4

> `DataFormat.Error` : Désolé... Nous n'avons pas pu analyser l'entrée
> fournie à une valeur Date. Détails :
> 1

Can you guys tell me if there is a dynamic way to infer the types of columns ?

Comment: The best approach might be to not change the data types at all, just leave them as `any` until after you combine / transform them, or even just load them to the spreadsheet as text. That should at least fix the problem of missing / new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface, you can use transform ... detect data type... but thats single use not dynamic

Otherwise it is a long and arduous journey

There as an attempt at this here [detect types](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Detect-type-of-column-in-Power-Query-Formula-Language/m-p/20518) but Im not convinced it works properly

Comment: Ok I understand that is complicated but I'll still check out the link. Thanks @horseyride.